# update product with same image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

i have a edit-form, and i have a problem, that the image added maybe will be the same (we will update other fields) or maybe change the image.

Before i had this to try:

```
let dataBody = {
 categoria: req.body.categoria,
 subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
 title: req.body.title,
 price: req.body.price,
 description: req.body.description, 
 images: {
 url: req.file.images // to get the new path from 
 cloudinary and mongodB
 filename: req.file.filename // to get the name of the 
 image file
  }

 }
```

if i changed for:

```
{images: {
    url: req.body.images // to get the path from body
    filename: req.body.imagesfilename // to get the name of 
    the image from body
      } }
```

if i use one or other, i achieved that i would. but i would like to have both options, so now,

In the server i try to do use this code: (because when not send a new image, the error is **'can not read property path of undefined'**) so i think that if i try to use this condition.....

```
const getCondition = () => {
    if (req.body.images !== undefined){
      console.log('vamos bien')
     {url= req.body.images,
      filename= req.body.imagesUrl}    
    }else{  
       {url= req.file.path,
        filename= req.file.filename}
    }
  }
  const result = getCondition()

  let dataBody = {
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,    
  }  

  let newData = {
    ...dataBody,
    images: {...result}
    
  }
```

and newData, goes in:

```
  const producto = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,           
      { $set: newData },
      { new: true }
    );
    
    console.log(producto);
    res.json({ producto });
   // await producto.save()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Hubo un Error");
  }
```

how can i achieve my goal, using a conditional to pass the values of the object?.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

To solve it I have found an answer that I leave here as code and the link of the person who solved it.

to identify that the sent file was undefined and then add to the images object with the new values ​​or not ...

```
...(typeof(req.file)!=="undefined" && {
      images: {
        url: req.file.path,
        filename: req.file.filename,
      }
    })
```

in such a way that my object remains this way.

```
let dataBody = {
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    ...(typeof(req.file)!=="undefined" && {
      images: {
        url: req.file.path,
        filename: req.file.filename,
      }
    }),
  };
```

much simpler. It did not happen that the undefined was given because the object itself was undefined, not the value of the variable.

the link of the person who solved it is this.  [Request body/file empty or not in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191440/request-body-file-empty-or-not-in-node-js)